# Django-rest-framework: Validate a ListSerializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I receive a number of similar objects as an input for my API, and I deserialize them using my own serializer with the parameter `many=True` like this:

```
serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
```

The `serializer` is an instance of `ListSerializer`.

Then I need to make sure that there are certain combinations of objects in that list. However, I don't seem to find a way to write a `.validate()` method on the `ListSerializer` of replace it by my own `ListSerializer` implementation.

Is there a way to do this validation in the serializer, or do I have to iterate over the deserialized objects and check them?

Comment: The Django REST frameworks documentation has a section on [Customizing `ListSerializer` behavior](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior)

Comment: @Kendas Looks exactly like what i need ) If you post this as a reply, i will gladly accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django REST frameworks documentation has a section on [customizing `ListSerializer` behavior](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior).

This entails creating a custom subclass of `ListSerializer`. You would probably want to create some custom validation in your subclass.